# Change order item name of an existing order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, class, methods, woocommerce

I'm trying to change order item names of existing order product by using this codes

```
$order = wc_get_order('14851');
foreach($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_obj){
     $item_obj->set_name($current_product_name.' Append This (S10)');
}
```

Woocommerce Documentation: [Class WC_Order_item: `set_name()` method](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html#method_set_name)

But it doesn't working at all. Can someone have an idea to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`save()`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html#method_save) method as follow:

```
$order_id = 14851;

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $item->set_name( $item->get_name() . ' Append This (S10)' );
    $item->save();
}

$order->save();
```

Woocommerce Documentation related methods:

- [Class WC_Order_item: `get_name()` method](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html#method_get_name)
- [Class WC_Order_item: `set_name()` method](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html#method_set_name)
- [Class WC_Order_item: `save()` method](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item.html#method_save)
- [Class WC_Abstract_Order: `save()` method](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Abstract-Order.html#method_save)

Comment: Greate , but how can add this with editable item in order woocommerce  ?